# Angular Unit test: CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA Error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

having troubles with Unit tests. I've a new project that asking to help fix test , I am adding "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" so that angular does not go deeper in children component and I am getting this error below that I am not clear why.

```
Unexpected value 'custom-elements' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

Componet Spec here

```
describe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
  let component: CheckboxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckboxComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [ CheckboxComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckboxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You delete CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA from TestBed.configureTestingModule's imports. And add TestBed.configureTestingModule's schemas

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule(
        imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [ CheckboxComponent ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

And if you import in CheckboxComponent class, import same module in TestBed.configureTestingModule.

And write "schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]" in CheckboxComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and simple

It's not import but 'schemas'

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        declarations: [ Component ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
```